# JMS, how to implement request-reply pattern using two message brokers

Tags: apache-camel, jms, integration, message-queue, messaging

Is it possible to implement asynchronous request-reply pattern using **two** JMS message broker instances? Such that service A sends message to queue A, and gets the response from queue B (different broker instance)?

Does JMS API (or Apache Camel) provide some complete mechanism to achieve this transparently with correlation identifiers? What is the necessary configuration?

Bonus question:

To shuffle deck even more, I would like to cluster the queues. Could this be achieved transparently as per specification? Basically I have multiple Spring boot applications (services) with ActiveMQ broker embedded in the Spring context. Each broker acts as an **one-way** channel for the service, and each service excepts a response for a specific message to other service in it's own broker. Now, I would like run multiple instances of each services and retain the correlation between messages.

Answer (score 0):

Since your request sender (A) and response receiver (B) are two different services - it becomes your responsiblity to store context of original request somewhere.

Probably the easiest is to use a dedicated queue for this purpose (let's call it echo).

(A) could store original request message with some specific correlation Id, for example taken from message Id of request sent. The same correlation Id is supposed to be set for response message, which will be taken by (B). So once response is recieved by (B), it is able to get the original request from echo queue, using selector with the same correlation Id.